# Disallow redirects from another site

Tags: redirects

A less than reputable site is redirecting to mine.  Short of taking legal action, is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What web server? Apache .Htaccess will allow you to block by referrer. Others too. The answer depends upon the web server.

Comment: Is this other site linking directly to your site? Or are they literally "redirecting"? In which case, _how_ are you detecting this "redirect"?

Comment: They are literally redirecting. I know because when enter their domain in a browser it redirects to mine.

Comment: @closetnoc The referrer probably won't help.   Redirects almost never cause browsers to send the URL of the redirecting domain.   Rather they [send the URL of page that links to the redirecting domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158283/will-a-302-redirect-maintain-the-referer-string/5441932#5441932).

Comment: Why do you want to disallow redirects from another site?   Redirects change the URL visible to users, so it isn't like your content is being framed, stolen, or misappropriated.    Even if the domain is something negative, most users will never find it.

Comment: The redirecting website belongs to someone who is employing questionable business practices and who used to be affiliated with the company my site belongs to. There was a schism and the company separated into two entities, the first business’ site is has a very negative fraud report from the Better Business Bureau. The BBB report contains a link to the first business’ site, which in turn redirects to ours.  They’re using the redirect to force an unwanted affiliation. Making it look like the fraud report is about our business when it is in fact not.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes. You are right. Brain f@rted! Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't say what server, assuming it is Apache and *mod_rewrite* is enabled

To set-up block a single referrer, create a .htaccess file and include the following text:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} otherdomain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: I’ve since verified that it is Apache. I’ll give your answer a shot. Thank you.

Comment: The referrer probably won't help.   Redirects almost never cause browsers to send the URL of the redirecting domain.   Rather they [send the URL of page that links to the redirecting domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158283/will-a-302-redirect-maintain-the-referer-string/5441932#5441932).

Comment: I’m asking this on behalf of someone else, my marking of your answer will probably not be for a while because I’m waiting to hear back from another person.

Comment: Based on the clarification to the question in the comment, you would have to block links from the better business bureau in the referrer, but there is probably no way to tell if the links came through a redirect or not.